# C++ memory layout of inherited virtual class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

Regarding the size of the derived class, is it better to have a "chain" of inheritance or inherit everything in the lowest derived class?

for example, what is better between:

```cpp
class Base {
  virtual void something() = 0;
};

class Derived1 {
  // ...
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1, public Base {
  // ...
};
```

and

```cpp
class Base {
  virtual void something() = 0;
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
  // ...
};

class Derived2 : public Derived1 {
  // ...
};
```

In the second case, will it have to store two vtable pointers and just one in the first case?

In the first case, I have a `sizeof(Derived)` lower that in the second case.

Comment: That depends on the design and requirements. If a `Base` is going to be reused by other derived classes, then it is necessary since it can implement all the common functionality for them. If there is no such need then you can certainly use MI. There is a separate `vtbl` 
 for each parent class, but that is implementation-specific. Virtual tables are not supposed to be directly visible or usable.

Comment: Depending on what you're doing in the classes in the first one , you might be seeing empty base class optimization

Comment: Interestingly, if `Derived1` has any virtual member functions, [the "big three" compilers will actually use less space for the second case than the first, because they like to reuse vtables whenever they can](https://godbolt.org/z/UGqK6F).  It's easiest to see with MSVC's layout output, but you can find sizes in the other two with a bit of sifting.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing as far as i can see is simply an empty base class optimization.
See the godbolt I've prepared. When you don't have empty classes, the sizes are identical.

https://godbolt.org/z/HhiJz6

To specifically address your question `Regarding the size of the derived class, is it better to have a "chain" of inheritance or inherit everything in the lowest derived class?`

I guess if you have an empty base class in there, you could claim it to be "better" in terms of size of the class, but that is pretty dependent on the specifics of the way the class is defined that could change at any time.
I wouldn't base an inheritance structure on it unless i was *really* pressed for space.